# Any graphics library for unix that can draw histograms?

Tags: python, unix, graphics

A python program needs to draw histograms. It's ok to use 3rd party library (free). What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist).

Comment: Thaks. Exactly what's needed.

Answer (score 3):

[Gnuplot.py](http://gnuplot-py.sourceforge.net/) lets you use [Gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) from python.

Answer (score 1):

How much power do you need? How much external weight are you willing to take on? [ROOT](http://root.cern.ch/) is accessible in python [using PyROOT](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/how-use-use-python-pyroot-interpreter). Heavy and a lot to learn to get the most out of it, but very powerful.